Future bond value and the role of the conversion factor
The fair value of a standardized future contract is updated every day based on the bid and offer price on the market. From my understanding this value F(t) is the value that the long is willing to pay to the short seller in exchange for the cheapest to delivery. However, taking into account the conversion factor, what will be traded at the settlement day of the contract will be the cheapest to delivery $B^{CTD}$ in exchange for $Cf^{CTD} \cdot F(t_0)$ money, where $F(t_0)$ is the price it was agreed when the contract was stipulated and $Cf^{CTD}$ is a conversion factor to adjust for the fact that a future contract is assumed to correspond to a standardized bond contract.  But then, it would seem to me that if one wants to close its position, or even just post margins mark to market, then the value of the contract should be $Cf^{CTD} \cdot F(t)$ not $F(t)$.
What am I missing here?

Cf changes depending on which bond you deliver. That is kind of its purpose  eg if you deliver a very low coupon bond, usually its cf <<1, so fut ×cf is lower vis a vis a high coupon bond.

Regarding the last sentence. All future markets work the same (for example Gold futures): when you get out of your position you get the price that the market is setting for the future at that moment (the actual price of the spot or underlying commodity does not matter. In theory of course there is a relation between the two, but its the price on the futures exchange that counts). Similarly the mark to market is calculated based on the price of the future as observed by exchange officials at a specified time, again without any reference to where spot gold is trading.

So in practice if I buy today a future at price F(t0) and hold it until delivery, with a last traded price of F(tf) my net PnL will be {F(tf)-F(t0)} +{ CF* F(tf)- B(tf)  } where B(tf) is the price of the bond on the last trading date? Essentially the first difference is due to marking to market the position and the second one is the price at which the underlying is delivered, right?

On the optimal delivery date you can assume that the basis has converged. Therefore, in your notation F(tf) = B(tf)/CF for the cheapest to deliver. Therefore, transaction costs aside, your pnl in total is F(tf)-F(t0)

Even when there is a clear CTD and the Futures moves exactly aligned with the CTD Bond, the size of the 2 securities is not the same.
1 CTD and 1 Futures have different sizes are risk (DV01).
Imagine you want to hedge 1 CTD, you will to buy CF futures, not 1.
This is why people normally think in terms of DV01 (or risk), and say 10k DV01 (of bond or of futures). The actual notional will be different.
And important to realise too that if you go to delivery, for each 1 Futures long, you will receive 1 CTD, so your risk will immediately change in magnitude.
